# Почему не делается скриншот?

Tags: python, screenshots, pil

мне нужно каждую секунду делать скриншот.
Я использую этот код:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from time import sleep

sleep(8)
a = 1
name = 'screenshot'
while a < 50:
  name = 'l/screenshot'+str(a)+'.png'
  screen = ImageGrab.grab()
  screen.save(name,'PNG')
  print('save: screenshot',a,'.png')

  a = a+1
```

Все работает отлично за исключением того что мне нужно делать их в игре Geometry Dash
Дело в том что скриншоты в этом приложении не делаются и программа сохраняет 100 скриншотов меню.

Буду рад если вы мне поможет, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант: запустить игру в окне, скринить экран, после чего обрезать изображение по разрешению игры

Comment: А где задержка в одну секунду-то?

Answer (score 3):

Вот эта вот конструкция

```
while a < 50:
    ...
    a = a+1
```

срабатывает только пока `a` меньше 50. И, так как на каждом шаге вы прибавляете к `a` единицу, то оно никак не может отработать больше 49 раз.

Кроме того, у вас внутри цикла нет никаких задержек в 1 секунду - то есть все 49 скриншотов будут сделаны сразу. Вот у вас и получается только одно меню.